# SQL Constraint Exception Error Code 19-Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

**DBAdapter :**

```
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

                    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_FIRSTNAME
                            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MIDDLENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                            + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MAIL_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                            + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CONFIRM
                            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH
                            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_COUNTRY + " TEXT NOT NULL "
                            + ");");
```

**RegPage.java :**

```
        dbadapter = new DBAdapter(RegistrationPage.this);
                            dbadapter.open();
                            dbadapter.insertRecord(first_name, middle_name, last_name,
                                    user_name, mail_id, pass_word, confirm_password, d_o_b,coun_try);
```

**Logcat**

```
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898): Error inserting username=arrfan30@gmail.com middlename=MOHAMMED  dob=22/11/1990 confirmpassword=black lastname=Rani  firstname=Raja password=black mail_id=arrfan30@gmail.com
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:112)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1732)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at com.example.signup.DBAdapter.insertRecord(DBAdapter.java:111)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at com.example.signup.RegistrationPage$1.onClick(RegistrationPage.java:83)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3100)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11644)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    12-06 11:54:45.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(4898):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

> While trying to insert the logcat says "`Error inserting data`" and SQL constraint exception error code 19. Can somebody help me ?? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

> I have also thrown in my logcat. I am not passing any null values.

Comment: please post whole logcat error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logcat shows that the country value is missing. Its not able to insert or get the column named country may be.

Make sure the country value is not null.

Try to insert records as below:

```
dbadapter.insertRecord(user_name, middle_name, d_o_b,confirm_password,last_name
                 ,first_name,pass_word,mail_id,coun_try);
```

Comment: Why would i want to create another instance of SQLite database while i already have it ?

Comment: If you have already created instance then you can use it. Here i have just shown you the way to insert values.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I was able to insert into database without any issues but today there seems to be a glitch and i inserted without any date format class. It worked like a charm then, this constraint is what causing me the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting all the values ? Not a singly value is null ?

Comment: It is evident from the logcat that all the values are accounted for and none of them is null.

Comment: Its showing that the country value is missing in your logcat. Check out carefully.

Comment: I just got it pal... Lots of thanks for ya.... I was doing a silly mistake by not getting the dob value from the database at the receiver end.  Thanks mate. Much appreciated.

Comment: Greatful to help you man. :) Vote the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

> Constraint failed usually indicates that you did something like pass a
>   null value into a column that you declare as not null when you create
>   your table.

So can you check any values you are passing are not null by debugging the code.

Comment: Thanks pal. Much appreciated. See my logcat, I am not passing ny null values.